# How to fix a function that is not firing using server cron?

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a server cron where a function will be triggered every 30 minutes. The problem is the data is not sending properly, but working when button is clicked or I use 'init' in the function. Also, the cron is properly triggering, added a sending mail function below the code that is needed to be triggered.

```
function myprefix_custom_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['every_30_minutes'] = array(
        'interval' => 30 * 60, // Every 30 minutes
        'display'  => __( 'Every 30 minutes' ),
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'myprefix_custom_cron_schedule' );

//Schedule an action if it's not already scheduled
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'myprefix_cron_hook' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_30_minutes', 'myprefix_cron_hook' );
}
//myprefix_cron_hook

add_action ( 'myprefix_cron_hook', function(){


//this is not being triggered
    $to_create_posts = true;
    $data = RemoteCoin::LoadRemoteCoin( $to_create_posts );


//this is the test email cron (working)
    $to = '***';
    $subject = 'Test my 30-minute cron job';
    $message = 'If you received this message, it means that your 30-minute cron job has worked!'; 
    mail( $to, $subject, $message, 'From: ***' . "com" );

});
```

But this is working when the button I created is clicked:

```
if(array_key_exists('mysubmitbtn3',$_POST)){
        $to_create_posts = true;
         $data = RemoteCoin::LoadRemoteCoin( $to_create_posts );
}
```

Also, this is working too, using init:

```
add_action ( 'init', function(){

    $to_create_posts = true;
    $data = RemoteCoin::LoadRemoteCoin( $to_create_posts );


});
```

I'm not sure where to start since it is not outputting any errors.
Anyone can help me where to start? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After days of debugging, I finally found the problem. It is the admin check function (which checks if the one that triggers it is an admin), I needed to remove it since the function will be triggered by the server, not an individual.

Thank you!